# Using StaticQuery for a dynamiclly built query string

Tags: scala, slick, shapeless

```
StaticQuery.queryNA[(String, String)](query)
```

where `query` String gets constructed dynamically (programmatically)  so number of columns returned from the query isn't known ahead of time.

sample query

```
select 
  (select field->>'value' from json_array_elements(vcolor.field_ids_json->'fields') as field where (field->>'ddid')::int = 113)
  as mycolor
, 

  (select field->>'value' from json_array_elements(ins.field_ids_json->'fields') as field where (field->>'ddud')::int = 131)
  as insp
```

above query is built programmatically and may have 10 or 20 such sub-queries each returning one value.

What's the best way to write such a dynamic function queries like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get a `Map[String, String]` out of a query. ALso works for `queryNA`.

[Slick: query multiple tables/databases with getting column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262036/slick-query-multiple-tables-databases-with-getting-column-names)